# Outlook Redemption - eml to pst - Specify folder Hiarachy

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm using Outlook redemption(http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) and following C# code to generate a PST file from .eml files.

```
            RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
            RDOPstStore store = session.LogonPstStore(newpstpath);
            RDOFolder folder = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Item(directoryEmlFile);
            if (folder == null)
            {
                folder = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Add(directoryEmlFile);
            }

            RDOMail mail = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note");
            mail.Import(directoryEmlFile + "\\0a53e310-b841-43bf-9586-8e7ddb4cd175" + ".eml");
            mail.Sent = true;
            mail.Save();
            store.Save();
```

It creates a PST file but when I import it to outlook the folder structure is similar to this.

```
Personal Folders
  -C:\Users\asanka\eml
```

Inside C:\Users\asanka\eml folder I can see the imported email. That is the folder where .eml file was originaly located. I need to get rid of that and have the folder structure like this.

```
Personal Folders
  -asanka
    -inbox
```

How can I do that? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the folder name you are passing to `Folders.Add`, right? You need to pass the appropriate name (asanka) to create the folder. You will probably need to do that twice since you have two folders:

```
RDOFolder folder1 = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Item("asanka");
if (folder1 == null) folder1 = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.Add("asanka");
RDOFolder folder = folder1.Folders.Item("Inbox");
if (folder == null) folder = folder1.Folders.Add("Inbox");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my code as you instructed. But now I'm getting an exception when mail.Import line executed. It says {"Error importing: 0x80030050"} System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

Comment: The error code is STG_E_FILEALREADYEXISTS. You are not specifying the format when calling Import, so Redemption defaults to olMsg. Specify rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822

Comment: I undid your changes to my answer - your code is ;less efficient as it calls folder.Folders.Item("Inbox") twice. This will result in an RPC call in on online profile. Not the end of the world, but it is an extra performance hit for no good reason. You might even want to cache the value of folder.Folders to avoid invoking it twice for each subfolder.

Comment: I used your code but got a null pointer exception while executing this line. if (folder == null) folder = folder.Folders.Add("Inbox"); That's why I changed the code like that. :) If the folder is null how can we call folder.Folders() method on a null object :)

Comment: I'm trying to run the same application as a web application. In that case I'm getting following error. Error in IProfAdmin::CreateProfile: MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED. Do I need to install exchange server in order to work that properly?

Comment: What is the local user used to run your IIS code? It needs to have local rights for the MAPI system to work properly.

Comment: I ran it using visual studio. I'm new to C#. I just built a web API application in visual studio 2012 and run it. Do I need to start visual studio as Administrator? I am logged in as a administrator user.

Comment: VS uses IIS Express when debugging. Have you tried to enable Windows authentication in applicationhost.config ?

Comment: it was set to false by default. I enabled it using applicationhost.config and restated the computer. Still no luck. Same error. And I made overrideModeDefault="Allow" too.

Comment: I tried it under IIS too. same issue. I have no idea what is wrong with IIS. I created a self hosted web application. Now it seems working though.